# Does Heat Sink work after hitting the Jackpot?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

The Heat Sink can be used to CPU counter when playing as the Robot. The Robot's Jackpot is activated when you hit the exact CPU limit. What happens if I use Heat Sink after hitting the jackpot? Does it undo my jackpot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using Heat Sink after hitting the Jackpot has no effect. The Heat Sink and whatever dice used to activate it are used up, but Jackpot remains in effect and you are unable to calculate more dice.